# Изменить параметры в переменной при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, мне нужно динамически настройку в скрипте при клике на блок.

Есть такой скрипт:

```
var settings = {

    // Keyboard shortcuts.
    keyboardShortcuts: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via keyboard shortcuts.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the distance to scroll when using the left/right arrow keys.
        distance: 50

    },

    // Scroll wheel.
    scrollWheel: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via the scroll wheel.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the scroll wheel factor. (Ideally) a value between 0 and 1 (lower = slower scroll, higher = faster scroll).
        factor: 1

    },
```

Где scrllWheel есть enabled: true, мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на блок с класом .card значение менялось на false.

Предистория: Есть сайт с горизонтальной прокруткой. ри нажатии на блок появляется окно с вертикальным скроллом. Но скрипт не дает прокрутить в низ так как отвечает за горизонтальную прокрутку. При изменении насройки на false сайт перестает скроллится но окно начинает работать как надо. Тут я и пришел к тому чтобы менять настройку при нажатии на блок открытия.

Comment: Это повтор или что? Я уже видел 100% точно такой же вопрос ранее и на него были ответы.

Comment: Вчера я задавал похожий вопрос, с другой формурелевкой. Ответа я не получил. К сожелению.

Comment: `$(".card").click(function(){ settings.scrollWheel.enabled = false; })` или что?

Comment: @teran Не заработало :((

Comment: ну вы откройте отладчик, поставьте точку останова в этот код, кликните  в блок. Если отладчик остановится, значит метод клика срабатывает. Если нет - значит криво добавили. Когда остановится в watches добавьте свой settings объект, и посмотрите как изменится значение.

Comment: @teran чесно гвооря, не совсем понял о чем Вы... Смотрел в консоле - ничего.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var settings = {

  // Keyboard shortcuts.
  keyboardShortcuts: {
    // If true, enables scrolling via keyboard shortcuts.
    enabled: true,
    // Sets the distance to scroll when using the left/right arrow keys.
    distance: 50
  },

  // Scroll wheel.
  scrollWheel: {
    // If true, enables scrolling via the scroll wheel.
    enabled: true,
    // Sets the scroll wheel factor. (Ideally) a value between 0 and 1 (lower = slower scroll, higher = faster scroll).
    factor: 1
  }
}

const card = document.querySelector('.card');
card.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  settings.scrollWheel.enabled = false;
  console.log(settings);
  });
```

```html
<div class="card"> click</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
*Во первых создаём переменную вне класса*/

    var scrollCheck = true;

 /* Внутри класса его иметь нет необходимости
Потом просто где маус листенер и кликер пишем*/

$(".card").click(function(){ if(class === .cards){
scrollCheck = false} ;
})


    var settings = {

    // Keyboard shortcuts.
    keyboardShortcuts: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via keyboard shortcuts.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the distance to scroll when using the left/right arrow keys.
        distance: 50

    },

    // Scroll wheel.
    scrollWheel: {

        // If true, enables scrolling via the scroll wheel.
        enabled: true,

        // Sets the scroll wheel factor. (Ideally) a value between 0 and 1 (lower = slower scroll, higher = faster scroll).
        factor: 1

    },
```